# Is there a way to find out which IF condition 'triggered' the entrance into if (){ } block?

Tags: java

In this example:

```
if (object instanceof SomeThing || object instanceof OtherThing) {
    System.out.println("this block was entered because of: " + **____** )
}
```

Could I check if the true condition was SomeThing or OtherThing?

edit: I'm trying to avoid the separation of conditions.

Thanks.

Comment: Create a second `if`.

Comment: Separate your `if` conditions.

Comment: or may be use a ternary operator in the System.out.println

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor any common steps in both cases to a function, and then:

```
if (object instanceof SomeThing) {
    // It's SomeThing
    System.out.println("Got here because it's SomeThing");
    commonStuff();
}
else if (object instanceof OtherThing) {
    // It's OtherThing
    System.out.println("Got here because it's OtherThing");
    commonStuff();
}
```

---

Re your edit:

> edit: I'm trying to avoid the separation of conditions.

Then you have these options:

```
if (object instanceof SomeThing || object instanceof OtherThing) {
    System.out.println("Got here because it's " +
        (object instanceof SomeThing) ? "SomeThing" : "OtherThing")
    );
}
```

Or

```
boolean isSomeThing:
if ((isSomeThing = object instanceof SomeThing) || object instanceof OtherThing) {
    System.out.println("Got here because it's " +
        isSomeThing ? "SomeThing" : "OtherThing")
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd option works the best for me, I forgot to mention that both of the conditions had a common second condition, property of _object_, so that will go in the top-level IF now.  Ex: if (object.property == 1) { * check for objects instanceof * }

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  if (object instanceof SomeThing ) {
        System.out.println("this block was entered because of: " + **SomeThing ____** )
    }   
  else if(object instanceof OtherThing){
     System.out.println("this block was entered because of: " + **OtherThing____** )
    }
  else{
     System.out.println("********nothing satisfied)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (object instanceof SomeThing || object instanceof OtherThing) {
     System.out.println(object instanceof SomeThing  );// if this print false then object is type of OtherThing

    System.out.println("this block was entered because of: " + **____** )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ternary operator:

```
 if (object instanceof SomeThing || object instanceof OtherThing) {
        System.out.println("this block was entered because of: " 
           + (object instanceof SomeThing? "SomeThing" : "OtherThing") );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("This block was entered because object is instance of SomeThing or OtherThing.");
```

As an alternative:

```
System.out.println("This block was entered because object is " + object.getClass().getName());
```

Or, very unreadable:

```
boolean other = false;
if (object instanceof SomeThing || (other = true) || ....) {
    System.out.println("because of " + other?"OtherThing":"SomeThing")
}
```